# how to get user entered password in spring security 3

Tags: spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I have implemented `UserDetailsService` and overriden `loadUserByUsername(String username)`, here i need User entered password.

I want to authenticate against `LdapTemplate authenticate(username,password)`.
I have searched a lot but dint get it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Either use [spring-security-ldap](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/ldap.html) for LDAP based authentication or implement your own `AuthenticationProvider` instead of `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

There are multiple authentication scenarios when using Spring Security LDAP:

- either you can retrieve the user entry via connection authenticated by the provided credentials (probably scenario you are looking for)
- or you can authenticate via technical account (usually you need to make LDAP search to get user's DN)

For more information check [Spring Security LDAP documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/ldap.html).